# Как получить handle всех вкладок google chrome?

Tags: c#, winapi, google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот все процессы с меткой "chrome". Открыто 5 вкладок.
Находит только активную вкладку. Если изменить активную вкладку, то у неё будет тот же wHnd

Первое окно через EnumWindows, второе через Process.GetProcesses();

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что у неактивной вкладки вообще есть hwnd?

Comment: Как же работать с неактивными вкладками тогда ? Их нельзя перебрать ?

Comment: Ну, хром вовсе не обязан предоставлять возможность работать внешним программам с его вкладками (я не знаю, есть ли такая функциональность на деле). Но вы можете написать расширение, по идее оно должно позволять.